# Pop/push view under modal

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view that slides up covering the visible view.
Based on button presses on the modal, I'd like to pop the view it covers and push a different view so when the modal slides down again the new view is visible.

What are so strategies to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the navigation controller stack you can access previous view controller, and on action you can change the view of that controller, use something like -

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray =  [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
// Replace your earlier view controller/view with new view controller/view , and then assign again the navigation controller's viewControllers

self.navigationController.viewControllers = activeControllerArray;
```

Comment: When I try this, all that's in that array is the view in the *modal.* That can't be right, can it? I tried `[[[self parentViewController] navigationController] viewControllers]` too, but that's just nil.

Comment: Oh, wait, I know why; it's because this modal has its own UINavigationController so that I can put the "Cancel" and "Done" buttons in it. Hmm.